# How to assign count_character to variable in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I can't for the life of me figure how to get the count of $var.description using count_characters. Here is what I did use:

```
{assign var="Counted" value="$var.description|unescape|count_characters"}
```

But it returns: $var.description||unescape|count_characters and not the count of the variable.

HELP PLEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign variables to another variable, do not wrap the variable in quotes:

```
{assign var="Counted" value=$var.description|unescape|count_characters}
```

If you are passing an array to a function, you might have to use the `@` operator:

```
{assign var="Counted" value=$var.description|@unescape|@count_characters}
```

If you need to include text AND a variable, use quotes and wrap the variable in "`" ("backticks")

```
{assign var="Counted" value="`$var.description` plus other text"|unescape|count_characters}
```

As you see, no matter how I am assigning the variable, I do not put the names of functions within quotes. The pipe-function_name format belongs outside any quoted text in all cases.